# Should use same ISP for Tor and Real life?

Tags: anonymity, deanonymization, connection

Should I use same ISP for connecting to Tor and for connecting to my real life sites like email and other sites where my Last Name and First Name figure ? I know about VPNs, Bridges and other things but on Whonix website they typed "They won't help against Global Adversaries". Also I've read on Hidden Wiki that is better to use your own router and ISP than a hacked Wifi. Soo my question is should have 2 ISP providers one for real life stuff and other to connect to Tor or no ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct problem in connecting to Tor from the connection that you also use to perform other activities, *assuming* that it is safe for you to use Tor in the first place (I.E. that it's not illegal for you to use Tor in the first place).

Infact the more people who can openly use Tor, the safer that it will be to use Tor since it's use will lose ground as some part of probable cause.

There are arguments to be made for using a distinct connection for some activities or providing some kind of cover for your traffic to make it less obviously Tor but for most peoples use cases that's really not required.

Answer (score 0):

You should ***not*** connect to any sites with you real-life info.
It's makes you unanonymous.

Also please take a look at this: https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en#warning

Comment: It does not make Tor "totally insecure", it simply means that you are not anonymous. Anonymity and security are different properties and we should avoid conflating them.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Kinda mix that up somehow. Will change.